# How to Generate a data in Gridview While using Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, gridview

[Some Code Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4hVF.jpg)

I Want to view my data in a gridview from database where i already create a Stored Procedure from which i want to Show a Data in GridView.But i don,t have any idea how to Show a Data in GridView.Please Give me a Code through which i can show a data in Grid View.

Comment: stop posting pictures of code. this is not facebook

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.May be It's useful

```
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select_Lab_Complete_Patient_Hist", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DATE;
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adp.Fill(dt);
        grd_lab_comp.DataSource = dt;
        grd_lab_comp.DataBind();
        dt.Clear(); dt.Dispose();
        adp.Dispose();
        cmd.Cancel(); cmd.Dispose();
        con.Close(); con.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        lbl_msg.Text = err.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: this one is not working for me because i am trying to retrieve data from Entity Data Model not from connection String.

Comment: @Shamskhan - you should have mentioned that in your question... which contains no code or examples whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help .I am using EF 6.1.3

in sql server

```
Create proc mysp
as 
BEGIN
select * from CmnUsers
END
```

and .cs file

```
 using (var db=new testEntities())
 {
      List<CmnUser> users = db.Database.SqlQuery<CmnUser>("mysp").ToList();
      GridView1.DataSource = users;
      GridView1.DataBind();

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Huh?! Someone gave you a negative point and I can see why! The question is too broad and could mean anything from how to get data into a `Gridview`, to how to get data, to how to use `Stored Procedures` in ASP.net, etc etc.

To avoid code-behind, as I prefer to give as much control to the ASP client as possible, this is what I do...

Define your SQL datasource referring to the stored procedure:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsWEFall" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ATCNTV1ConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="MyStoredProcName" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Param1" Type="string" />
..
etc
..
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And when you need it code-behind (C# for me), I just open the data source, read the data into a datatable and use it! Easy man!

```
            SqlDataSource sds1 = (SqlDataSource)gvRow.FindControl("sdsWEFall");
            sdsWEFall.SelectParameters["Param1"].DefaultValue = "a value";
            DataSourceSelectArguments dss1 = new DataSourceSelectArguments();
            DataView dv2 = sdsWEFall.Select(dss1) as DataView;
            DataTable dt2 = dv2.ToTable() as DataTable;
            if (dt2 != null)
            {
              foreach (DataRow dr2 in dt2.Rows)
                if (dt2.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                   //and do your stuff here
                }
            }
```

To put that data into a gridview, just link the GridView to the datasource and Bind() it!

```
MyGridView.DataSourceID = "sdsWEFall";
MyGridView.DataBind();
```

Voila!